# Word addin development and installation for Mac OS

Tags: c#, macos, office-addins, word-addins

I have developed an addin for MS Office Word using 2010 project template (VSTO C#)
It is working in Windows Office Word. Now I need to install it in Mac OS ? Is it possible ?

Do you have any link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSTO technology is not supported on Mac OS.

If you need an add-in that runs on both platforms, then you need to use the Office JavaScript "web add-in" functionality (which also works in the on-line versions of Office and on iPad, by the way).

This is a good place to start in the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

For support, use the office-js tag here on Stack Overflow.